# Min ID group by column in another table

Tags: sql, group-by, min

I think this is pretty straight forward, however I have not been able to get it to work using a partition or group by.  I need to get the lower of the two dim keys, however I still need to grab the territory dim key as I am using it in another part of the query outside of this subquery.

```
    SELECT 
ac.ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY,
iid.CUST_ID,
ter.TERRITORY_DIM_KEY,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY iid.CUST_ID ORDER BY ac.ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY) AS MIN_ACCT_KEY
FROM   DEXODS.OPUB_MDM_CCV_ID iid,
       DEXWHS.D_ACCOUNT_VEEVA ac,
       DEXWHS.D_TERRITORY ter
WHERE  ac.IMS_ID = iid.VAL_1_ID
AND    SUBSTR(ac.PRIMARY_TERRITORY, 1, 8) = ter.TERRITORY_CODE
AND    ac.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y' 
AND    iid.SCNDY_ID_TYP_XID = 202325 
AND    iid.cust_id = '53050249'
AND    MIN_ACCT_KEY= 1
```

my desired result is to return only account dim key 307070
ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY CUST_ID TERRITORY_DIM_KEY   MIN_ACCT_KEY
307070          53050249    -3              1
2565820         53050249    43              2

any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Will you put in sample data

Comment: ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY CUST_ID  TERRITORY_DIM_KEY
2565820                          53050249 43 
307070                          53050249 -3 
my desired result is to return only account_dim_key 307070 (sorry this was included in the image attached)

Comment: But which territory dim key would you grab: 43 or -3?

Comment: which RDBMS?  SQL Server, oracle, postgresql, Mysql?  If the db supports window functions then you would use `ROW_NUMBER() (PARTITION BY iid.CUST_ID, ORDER BY ac.ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY)` and then select where that = 1.  If not supported you would do a sub query to find the minimum `account_dim_key` and then relate back to get the rest of the details of the record

Comment: @Matt I updated the code to use row number partition by however, when I try and add where min_acct_key = 1 I get an invalid identifier error.  I also tried it as a subqery but get the same error.  This is in an oracle database.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT ac.ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY AS ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY,
       iid.CUST_ID
       ter.TERRITORY_DIM_KEY
FROM DEXODS.OPUB_MDM_CCV_ID iid JOIN
     DEXWHS.D_ACCOUNT_VEEVA ac
     ON ac.IMS_ID = iid.VAL_1_ID JOIN
     DEXWHS.D_TERRITORY ter
     ON substr(ac.PRIMARY_TERRITORY, 1, 8) = ter.TERRITORY_CODE
WHERE ac.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y' AND
      iid.SCNDY_ID_TYP_XID = 202325 AND
      iid.cust_id = '53050249'
ORDER BY ac.ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Note:  `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` is ANSI standard SQL.  In some databases, this is spelled `LIMIT`, or `TOP 1`, or even more arcane ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
       ac.ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY,
       iid.CUST_ID,
       ter.TERRITORY_DIM_KEY,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY iid.CUST_ID ORDER BY ac.ACCOUNT_DIM_KEY) AS MIN_ACCT_KEY
    FROM
       DEXODS.OPUB_MDM_CCV_ID iid
       INNER JOIN DEXWHS.D_ACCOUNT_VEEVA ac
       ON ac.IMS_ID = iid.VAL_1_ID
       AND ac.ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
       INNER JOIN DEXWHS.D_TERRITORY ter
       ON SUBSTR(ac.PRIMARY_TERRITORY, 1, 8) = ter.TERRITORY_CODE
WHERE
    iid.SCNDY_ID_TYP_XID = 202325 
    AND    iid.cust_id = '53050249'
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    MIN_ACCT_KEY= 1
```

Based on what you wrote here is a way to do it for any number of customers just remove `iid.cust_id = '53050249'` and it will get the correct row per customer.  Note this is using Explicit join instead of Implicit join syntax.  The only error after your updating was attempting to refer to your column alias for your ROW_NUMBER() within the where statement.  That alias and column would not be available to you without wrapping the original query as a derived table or a common table expression.  I have shown the common table expression method.